# autocomplete is not calling action class

Tags: jquery, struts2, autocomplete

I want to show supplier name while user click on text box.For that i am using jquery.autocomplete.js. I am following [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery/)

My code is in jsp

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.autocomplete.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

        <style>
            input {
                font-size: 120%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
 <span class="label">Supplier Name</span>
    <span class="ib"> <input type="text" name="supplierId" id="supplierId"/></span>
  <script>
$("#supplierId").autocomplete("autoCompleteSupplier");
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

in struts.xml

```
<action name="autoCompleteSupplier" class="iland.supplier.SupplierAction" method="autoComplete">
            <result name="success">/pages/supplier/suggestion.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/supplier/suggestion.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

in action class

```
public class SupplierAction extends ActionSupport {
 private String q;//getter and setter method

 public String autoComplete() {

            System.out.println("->SupplierAction autoComplete()");
            System.out.println(getQ());
            SupplierBusiness cb = new SupplierBusiness();
            Map data = cb.autoComplete(getQ());
                setSupplierList((ArrayList) data.get("supplierList"));
                return SUCCESS;
     }
   }
```

the autocompte should display following jsp page

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<s:iterator value="supplierList" var="suplst">
    <s:property value="supplierId"/>
    <s:property value="supplierName"/>
</s:iterator>
```

While inspecting with crome it shows following error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery.autocomplete.js:462
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on autocomplete prior to initialization;
attempted to call method 'autoCompleteSupplier' jquery-1.9.1.js:507
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Put the call to `autocomplete` in your DOM-ready function, e.g., at the end of the HTML.
2. Use the `source` attribute to set the action. Use a complete URL, e.g. from an `<s:url>` tag.

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    source: "<s:url action='autoCompleteSupplier'/>"
  });
</script>
```

Note that this functionality is wrapped up in the [Struts 2 jQuery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/).